# Qt Reources - Add and Read JSON file

Tags: json, qt

I need a JSON file to save some info about my app and read it sometimes. And because my app runs in Ubuntu and Windows, I added it to Qt Resources...
To access the JSON file I tried:

```
QFile file(":/files/files/my_settings.json");
qDebug() << "settings file: " << endl << file.readAll();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to call `QFile::open()` before calling `readAll()`.

Second point, you can not write to file in Qt Resources.

If you want a cross platform way to save settings and such for your software take a look at `QStandardPaths::writableLocation()` and `QSettings`.

Note that QSettings won't handle JSON out of the box, but it will handle all the read/write to file for you (and the file format and location for you if you took car of setting `QCoreApplication::applicationName` and `QCoreApplication::organizationName`).

Comment: I used QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/settings.json" to use the json file

Comment: @vitor13almeida Using `applicationDirPath()` is a bad idea. On Windows you'll end up writing in `C:\Program Files` which is not writable for standard users. It is even worse on Linux distro such as Ubuntu as `applicationDirPath()` will be something like `/bin` or `/usr/bin` where you're only supposed to have executable files. To have a proper location for any OS use `QStandardPaths`

Comment: My app is in a USB drive and with QString settings_file_path = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/files/settings.json"; I can get the path just fine

Comment: In your case (a portable app) `applicationDirPath()` works. But you would have to change this if someday you want to package your app (i.e create a setup or .deb)